# display: table-cell; outside the table

Tags: html, css

Is it correct to use `display: table-cell;` outside a table or a div with `display: table`? 
For example, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnpax/

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to use display: table-cell; outside a table or a div
>   with display: table?

You can do that.

Any of the required but missing elements will be automatically generated as "anonymous" table elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

> Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous
>   table objects around itself, consisting of at least three nested
>   objects corresponding to a 'table'/'inline-table' element, a
>   'table-row' element, and a 'table-cell' element. Missing elements
>   generate anonymous objects (e.g., anonymous boxes in visual table
>   layout) according to the [rules described in the link above].

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in using it but you could have the same result be using [it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnpax/1/)

```
#number-one {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: block;    // changed table-cell to block
    height: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 300px;
}

#number-two {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 100px;    // add margins to 'push' the inside div to the position we want
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I use `display: table-cell;` for vertical align. Your way will work only with fixed sizes.

Comment: -1; this doesn't address the question asked. (Well, I suppose that *"There is no problem in using it"* addresses the question, but you've cited no evidence whatsoever for that claim so it doesn't exactly fill me with confidence.)